# Can I use exp() function inside PIC877A?

Tags: microcontroller

I compiled this code successfully in mikrocpro. But I can't get output in proteus. [image: These are the error messages shown in proteus]

This is the hex file link [HEX FILE](http://www.mediafire.com/view/0on6asyptge4qud/MyProject.hex):

```
          // LCD module connections
      sbit LCD_RS at RD4_bit;
      sbit LCD_EN at RD5_bit;
      sbit LCD_D4 at RD0_bit;
      sbit LCD_D5 at RD1_bit;
      sbit LCD_D6 at RD2_bit;
      sbit LCD_D7 at RD3_bit;
      sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
      sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
      sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
      sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
      sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
      sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD3_bit;
      // End LCD module connections

void main() 
{

      char ch;
      double m,a;
      m=5.10;
      a=exp(m);


      TRISD = 0x00; // PORTD is output

          Lcd_Init();                      // LCD display initialization
          Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);        // LCD command (cursor off)
          Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);             // LCD command (clear LCD)

    while(1)
    {
          ch=sin(3.14/2.)+800/100;
          Lcd_Chr(2,1,48+ch);
          Delay_ms(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi channa, welcome to eesx. You are posting error messages that are about assembled code but you are posting the source code, please include the asm (yes we can read it). Your piece of SW starts with lines of code that don't look like C to me, what is that? I am referring to the "sbit XXX at YYY;" lines. If you want a quick answer just read your **compiler** docs. The PIC does not support exp() for sure, but maybe the compiler has some routines to emulate it.

Comment: If it compiles and links you can use it.

Comment: i attached hex file link now

Comment: See http://www.mikroe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=29129.  I suspect you don't have enough RAM on that controller.  So long as you're just simulating anyway, why don't you try a bigger microcontroller and see if your problems go away?